# Using numpy arithmetic based on position in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am not quite sure how to describe my question, but I will try.

I want to know if numpy has the functionality to do this:

Lets say I have a 2D array called grid:

```
grid = [ [0,0],
         [0,0] ]
```

I also have a second 2D array called aList:

```
aList = [ [1,2],
          [3,4] ]
```

I want to apply math to the first array based on the index of the first array.

So the math done at each iteration would look like this:

```
grid[i][j] = [(i - aList[k][0]) + (j - aList[k][1])]
```

Currently doing this in python with for loops is way to expensive so I need an alternative.

EDIT: more clarification, if I were not to use numpy I would write something like this:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        num = 0 
        for k in range(2):
            num += (i-aList[k][0]) + (j-aList[k][1])
        grid[i][j] = num
```

This is however way to slow in python for the amount of data I have.

Comment: Could you please paste a small working copy of your script? It is hard to parse what is going on here. What is `k`?

Comment: If this is really what you are doing, and `k` is the iteration number, then notice that your expression can be simplified to `[i + j - c]` where `c = aList[k][0] + aList[k][1]`...

Comment: Sorry if I made this confusing, I knew I was going to be bad at explaining this. i, j, and k are all iterators. i and j are iterating over the entire 2D array grid. K is iterating over the array, aList at each spot in grid.

Comment: Can you please post your current code using for loops. This is very likely something numpy can help with.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be reproduced and substantially sped up as follows:

```
i_s = np.arange(2)
j_s = np.arange(2)

fast_grid = (i_s + j_s[:, None])*len(aList) - aList.sum()
```